# Is there a valid way of exporting a variable across different shells?

Tags: bash, zsh, ksh, variable

For some reasons, Im using `ksh` and `zsh` in my scripts and returning to `-bash`, I need to use already set variable values in the spawned shells, writing it to some temp file and using that didn't look like the way to go. Any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variable is exported (`bash`: by the `export` command or by default because of `set -a`) then a called shell gets it in its environment like any other process would.